# ASP.NET sqldatasource.select(arg) gives stackoverflow.exception error

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, sqldatasource

I have a code to read the total number of rows in a SQLDatasource:

```
Protected Sub DSArticles_Selected(sender As Object, e As SqlDataSourceStatusEventArgs) Handles DSArticles.Selected
    Dim args As DataSourceSelectArguments = New DataSourceSelectArguments
    Dim dv As DataView = DSArticles.Select(args)
    dv.RowFilter = DSArticles.FilterExpression
    LblCikkekSzama.Text = dv.Count & " cikk"
End Sub
```

The browser says the page cannot be viewed. When in debugging mode I get the error:
An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in mscorlib.dll.

Any ideas?
Thanks

Sudi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have a feeling you're causing an infinite loop because in the selected event you're doing Select() which triggers the selected event again, which calls Select again, etc...  So this is probably not a good place to do this.  Maybe move it to page_load or somewhere else that wouldn't trigger the selected event continuously.  Somewhere that makes sense for what you're trying to accomplish.